# How to use delogo with ffmpeg when logo starts at y=0

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a 1920x800 video, all content, no black bars. At the top of the frame (`y=0`) there is a station logo I want to remove (presumably the original capture was cropped, leaving a half of a station logo inside the usable frame). Since the logo I'm trying to remove starts at the very top of the frame and because the default `band=1` option that cannot be changed anymore (the option was seemingly removed from the API), the command needs to take it into account and make y=1:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "delogo=x=1696:y=1:w=113:h=32:show=1" output.mp4
```

but this breaks the interpolation, since that 1px on top is completely dirtying the box:
[Logo with show=1 so we see the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7JG4.png)

Tries with `y=0` fail with or without trying to specify the `band` width (with `band=0` or the alias `t=0`):

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "delogo=x=1696:y=0:w=113:h=33:band=0" output.mp4
[Parsed_delogo_0 @ 0000020528a7cf00] Option 'band' not found
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "delogo=x=1696:y=0:w=113:h=33:t=0" output.mp4
[Parsed_delogo_0 @ 000002b9b87acf40] Option 't' not found
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "delogo=x=1696:y=0:w=113:h=33" output.mp4
[delogo @ 0000023d971cd000] Logo area is outside of the frame.
```

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: `band` was deprecated in 2015 and I removed it last year. Forgot to update the docs. Use the pad filter to add vertical padding, delogo with adjusted y value, and then crop out the padded area.

Comment: Thanks for quickly answering! I tried that but now the black bar on top is the one bleeding into the box. I even tried delogo on the top bar, too, to make it mimic the top content, before delogo-ing the actual logo, but then we kind of have the same problem from the beginning: the logo is bleeding into the padding :)))

Comment: After padding and before logo, see if the fillborders filter helps.

Comment: I have not yet managed to find a solution to this.

-vf "pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, fillborders=left=0:right=0:top=140:bottom=140:mode=fixed, delogo=x=1705:y=130:w=113:h=40:show=1"

has the same output as

-vf "pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, delogo=x=1705:y=130:w=113:h=40:show=1"

(i.e. with bleeding).

It seems that the delogo filter needs some content in the section above, not just black.

A solution could be to force the delogo to start at y=0 and remove the padding/fillborders altogether. But there is no such possibility (anymore), right? :)

Comment: Pfoa, hearing my self thinking, I realized that using fillborders with 'mode=mirror' will give me the exact content I needed! It works like that!

Answer (score 2):

With the help of [Gyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5726027/gyan)'s comments, what finally solved the issue was using padding to increase the video top and bottom and get rid of the delogo limitation with `band=1`, then use fillborders with `mode=mirror` to extend the logo into the top area to avoid a black bar later bleeding into the delogo magic, then apply delogo and finally crop back to 1920x800:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "
  pad=1920:1080:0:(oh-ih)/2,
  fillborders=left=0:right=0:top=140:bottom=140:mode=mirror,
  delogo=x=1705:y=100:w=113:h=70:show=0,
  crop=w=1920:h=800:x=0:y=140
" -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Comment: can I ask you a question? For `-map 0:v:0`, I know the first `0` means the first input file(first `-i`), and `v` means the video stream of the first input file, but what does the last `0` mean?

Comment: The first video stream in that first input file (you can have several video streams in one file, not that there are so many players supporting that).